# Django Rest Framework Browsable Api Specify display/value pair for foreign key field dropdown

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

My model is as (only pseudocode)

```
class Country(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    Code= models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)

    def label(self):

        return self.Name + " - " + self.Code

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.label())


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.label())

class Mountain(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='mountain')
```

I have successfully created a custom foreign key serializers.RelatedField that displays "Name - Code" on read but only accepts the Code on write. This works fine using Postman.  However in my Browserble api I see a dropdown of countres displayed as  "Name - Code" but when i post it posts the Name field of the model.

I need send the Code field from the browsable api. How do I specify this and where. Primarily how do i specify what the display/value pair should be for a foreign key dropdown field in the browsable api